# Deploying contract using gnosis safe sdk on sepolia testne

Tags: safe-core

```
    throw new Error('SafeProxy contract is not deployed on the current network');
          ^
```

Error: SafeProxy contract is not deployed on the current network
at getSafeContract (/home/bishal/works/bisbist/gnosis-safe-demo/gnosis-poc/node_modules/@safe-global/protocol-kit/dist/src/contracts/safeDeploymentContracts.js:65:15)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async ContractManager.init (/home/bishal/works/bisbist/gnosis-safe-demo/gnosis-poc/node_modules/@safe-global/protocol-kit/dist/src/managers/contractManager.js:43:49)
at async ContractManager.create (/home/bishal/works/bisbist/gnosis-safe-demo/gnosis-poc/node_modules/@safe-global/protocol-kit/dist/src/managers/contractManager.js:28:9)
at async Safe.init (/home/bishal/works/bisbist/gnosis-safe-demo/gnosis-poc/node_modules/@safe-global/protocol-kit/dist/src/Safe.js:78:65)
at async Safe.create (/home/bishal/works/bisbist/gnosis-safe-demo/gnosis-poc/node_modules/@safe-global/protocol-kit/dist/src/Safe.js:54:9)
at async file:///home/bishal/works/bisbist/gnosis-safe-demo/gnosis-poc/deployContract.js:43:17

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of all supported networks for each version of the contracts [here](https://docs.staging.5afe.dev/supported-networks). Without more information on the contracts version used, it is difficult to give you more guidance on how to solve the problem.

Hope it helps, Louis

Answer (score 0):

Just updating the link from the other answer since this one works: https://docs.safe.global/smart-account-supported-networks

I got the same error trying to deploy a 1.1.1 on Sepolia, which makes sense, since it's not supported. But like the previous answer mentions, need more context.